# QML project gives 'unavailable type error' with CMake configuration (Qt 6.2)

Tags: cmake, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qt6

I have created a test project with Qt6.2-MinGW-64bit and I choose CMake.
The project structure is shown in the picture. Only 3 test files are embedded in each other and the first test file (test1.qml) is used in main.qml.

[image: Project structure]

Now when I want to start the program it gives a weird error that the Test2 is unavailable. I have tried different scenarios and have checked all steps in CMake but with no success.

Here is the main.qml:

```
import QtQuick
import untitled35

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property Test1 _example: Test1 {}
}
```

Here is the CMakeFile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(untitled35 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)

qt_add_executable(appuntitled35
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(appuntitled35
    URI "untitled35"
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        main.qml
        core/Test1.qml
        core/Test2.qml
        core/components/Test3.qml
)

set_target_properties(appuntitled35 PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_compile_definitions(appuntitled35
    PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(appuntitled35
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that Test2 has an error. `QtObject` does not have a default property to put the Test3 object you created inside of it. `Item` places child elements in its children, but `QtObject` does not make that assumption. try changing the `QtObject` to `Item`. [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties) for default properties and [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) for `Item` data property which is its default.